# Jquery Mobile listview not displaying

Tags: ajax, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app with the help of JQuery mobile that has four sections, each one has its own html file. The problem is, for instance, if I first load main.html and then navigate to list.html through a link, the listview in list.html does not show anything, but if I load list.html as the first page, it works perfect, I found this problem while testing on devices. Hope someone can help me fix this

Got this files as an example

--------clasificados.html--------------

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="clasificados">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header1" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Clasificados</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="vehiculos.html" data-transition="slide">Vehiculos</a></li>
                    <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="bienesraices.html" data-transition="slide">Bienes Raices</a></li>
                    <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="empleos.html" data-transition="slide">Empleos</a></li>
                    <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="diversos.html" data-transition="slide">Diversos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer1" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="main.html" id="periodico_icon" data-icon="custom"><br/>Periodico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="directorio.html" id="directorio_icon"  data-icon="custom"><br/>Directorio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id="clasificados_icon" data-icon="custom"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><br/>Clasificados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cuponera.html" id="cuponera_icon" data-icon="custom"><br/>Cuponera</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div>
```

-------vehiculos.html-------------

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="vehiculos" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Vehiculos</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul id='vehiculosOutput' data-role="listview">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer1" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="main.html" id="periodico_icon" data-icon="custom"><br/>Periodico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="directorio.html" id="directorio_icon"  data-icon="custom"><br/>Directorio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" id="clasificados_icon" data-icon="custom"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"><br/>Clasificados</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cuponera.html" id="cuponera_icon" data-icon="custom"><br/>Cuponera</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div>
```

-------vehiculos.js----------------

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {

               // retry not set or less than 2 : retry not requested
               if( !originalOptions.retryMax || !originalOptions.retryMax >=200 ) return;
               // no timeout was setup
               if( !originalOptions.timeout >0 ) return;

               if( originalOptions.retryCount ) {
                  // increment retry count each time
                  originalOptions.retryCount++;
               }else{
                  // init the retry count if not set
                  originalOptions.retryCount = 1;
                  // copy original error callback on first time
                  originalOptions._error = originalOptions.error;
               };

               // overwrite error handler for current request
               options.error = function( _jqXHR, _textStatus, _errorThrown ){
                  // retry max was exhausted or it is not a timeout error
                  if( originalOptions.retryCount >= originalOptions.retryMax || _textStatus!='timeout' ){
                     // call original error handler if any
                     if( originalOptions._error ) originalOptions._error( _jqXHR, _textStatus, _errorThrown );
                     return;
                  };
                  // Call AJAX again with original options
                  $.ajax( originalOptions);
               };
            });

            var output = $('#vehiculosOutput')

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.periodicosonofertas.com/mobile/conexVehiculos.php',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                success: 
                    function(data, status){
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        var vehicles = '<li>'+item.name + '<p></p>'
                        + '<p><font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small" >'+item.descripcion+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.contacto+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.telefono+'</p>' + '<p>'+item.correo+'</p></li>';

                        output.append(vehicles);

                    });
                    output.listview('refresh');
                },error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                 // display error status on failure
                 alert( 'error: ' + textStatus );
                }
                ,timeout:5000
                 ,retryMax: 200
            });
        });
```

Comment: first of all, dont use `.ready` replace it with `.on('pageinit', function ()` and try `output.listview().listview('refresh');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Ajax navigation, then jQM loads only the contents of the response's body element (or more specifically the `data-role="page"` element). The scripts and styles inside the `head` tag won't execute unless the page is requested via HTTP. This explains why the listview is displayed properly when the page is loaded as first page.

In conclusion there are two possible solutions to your issue:

Initially, replace `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$(document).on('pageinit', '#vehiculos', function(){` inside vehiculos.js. This action is required, regardless of which of the below solution you will select.

The first solution is to add the `vehiculos.js` script inside the main.html page's `head` tag:

```
<script src="vehiculos.js"></script>
```

The second solution is to include the `vehiculos.js` script inside the list.html page's div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="vehiculos" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the exact solution :)